# Refactoring array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the next array

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 22 [title] => RankTitle ) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 32 [title] => RankTitle2 ) 
)
```

How can I get the next array in php?:

```
Array ( 
   [22] => RankTitle 
   [32] => RankTitle2 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($old as $item) {
    $new[$item['id']] = $item['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
$array = Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( [id] => 22 [title] => RankTitle ) 
            [1] => Array ( [id] => 32 [title] => RankTitle2 ) 
         ) 

$nextArray = array($array[0]['id'] => $array[0]['title'],
                   $array[1]['id'] => $array[1]['title']);
```

Comment: Yes. But if I'll add 100 elements into my first array, this solution grows up in 100 times.

Comment: Yea I was just showing you the concept, it definitely doesn't scale =/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_column($oldArray, 'column_to_be_key'),
    array_column($oldArray, 'column_to_be_value'),
);
```